# How to make a bar chart on range of values on x-axis and count on the range on y-axis in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib

I have a list such as `[0.2,0.4,1.2,2.4,5.4,6.0,0.3,3.4..]` and I want to group the values in the list to a range(interval can change for different inputs) `0-1`,`1-2`,`2-3` and would like to plot a graph where the x-axis is the range and y-axis depicts the `no_of_values` in the given range?

For the above problem, `{0-1:3,1-2:1,2-3:1,3-4:1,4-5:0,5-6:2}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at the 'hist' function in Matplotlib?

Comment: You'll need to explicitly set bins. E.g.`plt.hist(yourlist, bins=np.arange(0,max(yourlist)+1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [pandas.DataFrame.hist](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html)

`pd.DataFrame(ls).hist()`

where `ls = [0.2,0.4,1.2,2.4,5.4,6.0,0.3,3.4]`

[image]